# Receiving "Workbook.getWorkbook() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values:" while reading excel using Groovy from SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, apache-poi

Could you anyone please findout the rootcause of the below error

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;

//def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
File file=new File("C://Users/toothless/Desktop/Don Delete/MyPractice.xlsx")
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file)
Sheet sheet=workbook.getSheet(0)
rc=sheet.getRows()
log.info rc
```

Following is my ext folder screenshot.
[image]

**I'm getting the following error while executing the above groovy code.**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.getWorkbook() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [C:\Users\toothless\Desktop\Don Delete\MyPractice.xlsx] error at line: 10
```

Comment: Don't you mean [WorkbookFactory.create(File)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-) ?

Comment: @Gagravarr No, it's already there in that location. I just want to read the content of existing file.

Comment: That's what it does, it identifies the file and opens it for you, see the linked javadocs!

Comment: Where did u get the method `Workbook.getWorkbook` xlsx and xls needs various classes for reading process ?

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi I just copied the snippet from a different source and trying to implement as per my requirement. Would be grateful if you some sample code of to read an excel.

Comment: Have u tried with my answer shown below ?

Answer (score 1):

First there is no method like you mention `Workbook.getWorkbook`. Ref [doc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html). Here your question to read excel file as workbook object use the code shown below,

**For xlsx files :**

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (file)
```

**For xls files :**

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook (file)
```

After that you can use these methods shown in [doc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook-java.io.File-) for further reading process.